# How do I use a string as a name of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use this program:

```py
name = input('name: ') # mark
age = int(input('age')) #23
name = age
```

`mark = 23`

I know that I can use a dictionary, but is there a way to create an actual variable with string?

I have absolutely no reason to do this and I understand it's pretty much unusable, but I wanted to try something new and came across a problem that could be fixed like this (but shouldn't be)

Comment: You should not do this. You *can* **but shouldn't** do this in the global scope. You cannot in local scopes.

Comment: Just do `{name: age}` and be happy. A lot better than `eval()`.

Comment: Maybe people can help you if you specify _why_ you want to do this.

Answer (score -5):

I found the answer to my question pretty quickly, but I'll leave it here for someone else:

```py
name = input('name: ') # mark
age = input('age') #23
with open("temp.py",'w') as f:
    f.write(name+" = "+age)
from temp import *
```

`mark = 23`

Comment: This might almost be a worse idea than using `eval` or `exec`. The overhead of writing to, then reading from, the file system is completely unnecessary for just simulating a variable.